# editor alternate tip message

Tags: extjs

I am trying to set 2 different tool tip message for 2 cells of single column,but on run time single tip message will be applied that is if am clicking on cell with respect to condition of if clause then same tip message will be forwarded to rest of the cells,if i navigate from 1 st cell to 2 cell message will not change 1 st cell message will carry forwards and vise versa if i move from 2nd cell to 1 cell 2nd tip message will remain same for rest of the cells.

```
celldblclick : function(grid, rowIndex, columnIndex, e) {
    var ed = grid.getColumnModel().getCellEditor(columnIndex,rowIndex) || {};
    ed = ed.field || {};

    if (rowIndex == 0 && columnIndex == 2) {
        ed.qtipText="SAMPLE1";
    } else {
        ed.qtipText="SAMPLE2";
    }
}
```

Comment: Which version of ext js do you use?

Answer (score 1):

To get them to display differently I normally attach a function to the tooltip `beforeshow` method which updates the tooltip before it is displayed:

```
// add tooltips to grid
myGrid.getView().on('render', function(view) {
    view.tip = Ext.create('Ext.tip.ToolTip', {
        target: view.el,
        delegate: view.itemSelector,
        trackMouse: true,
        minWidth: 0, 
        maxWidth: 800, 
        dismissDelay: 0,
        showDelay: 800,
        renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
        listeners:{
            beforeshow: function updateTipBody(tip){
                text = view.getRecord(tip.triggerElement).get('tooltip')
                tip.setWidth(text.length * 5);
                tip.update(text);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

In the above example I had my tooltips defined for each record in the datastore itself, that is why I call `text = view.getRecord(tip.triggerElement).get('tooltip')` ('tooltip' is the column in my datastore with the tooltip text). But you could implement whatever logic you want in the beforeshow listener function as long as you call `tip.update(yourLogic)` at the end.